# A simplicial analogue of a Hurewicz fibration

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a map of simplicial sets. Then there is an obvious simplicial version of demanding that $f$ be a ``Hurewicz'' fibration. Whether for every simplicial set $S$, $f$ has the lifting property with respect to the inclusion of $S$ into $S \times \Delta^1$, say via the 0th vertex or the 1st vertex of $\Delta^1$.

I suspect this definition does not have very good properties, and in my context, I am only interested in the case where it is a priori known that $X$ and $Y$ are already Kan complexes. (Note: Because $X$ and $Y$ are both assumed Kan complexes, it does not matter which vertex we include into.)

Question: Is it automatic that any map of Kan complexes which is a ``Hurewicz'' fibration in the above sense is also a Kan fibration? In other words, if a map of Kan complexes satisfies the right lifting property with respect to all maps of the form $i: S \to S \times \Delta^1$ (where $i$ is the inclusion of $S$ into, say the part of $S \times \Delta^1$ above the 0th vertex of $\Delta^1$), is it automatically a Kan fibration?

I am not an expert in simplicial or model-category-theoretic techniques. I would love a statement along the lines of how the class of inclusions of one end into cylinder objects somehow generate acyclic cofibrations, or some version of that statement when the $f$ in question is known to be a map between fibrant objects, but maybe that's too naive.